# ENOENT: no such file or directory! in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-8, laravel-mix

When I run `npm run dev` for Laravel Mix in webpack.mix.js, I get the following error: I don't know the problem. It just sticks to one of my files.

> [webpack-cli] [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users\AsemaN\Desktop\AryaBMS\resources\css\MainPage\sweetaleret2.all.min.css']
> {   errno: -4058,   code: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'open',   path:
> 'C:\Users\AsemaN\Desktop\AryaBMS\resources\css\MainPage\sweetaleret2.all.min.css'
> } npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! AryaBMS@1.0.0
> development: `mix` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at
> the AryaBMS@1.0.0 development script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
> problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\AsemaN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-01-26T19_09_23_305Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! AryaBMS@1.0.0 dev:
> `npm run development` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
> at the AryaBMS@1.0.0 dev script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
> problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\AsemaN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-01-26T19_09_23_491Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application expects to find a file at `C:\Users\AsemaN\Desktop\AryaBMS\resources\css\MainPage\sweetaleret2.all.min.css`. However, that file does not exist. `EOENT` means 'Error NO ENTity,' which translates to no directory or file was found in English. So you either need to create the expected directory/file or configure your application to look in the correct directory for sweetaleret2.all.min.css. Perhaps you misspelled the file name somewhere?